# Range and Caret position doesn't match

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I noticed this problem in MS Edge, the caret position and range doesn't match up or wrong inside a content editable.

```js
$("#c").click(function(e) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
 
  $("#res").get(0).textContent = "START_OFFSET:" + range.startOffset + "->" + range.startContainer.innerHTML;
  console.log("Range count: " + sel.rangeCount);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="c" contenteditable="true">
    <span>TEST</span>
  </div>
  <span id="res"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

In case if it is a hassle to open MS Edge, here's the snippet :

[image]

The result should be 4 -> TEST

Weird enough, the actual caret is pointing at the span node which contains an innerHTML of TEST but the start offset and end offset are showing 1. By the range data it is like this `|TEST` but visually it is `TEST|`.

Is there a way in solving this?

*Via JS, I can't seem to catch the correct information inside the range class to adjust properly the startOffset and endOffset unless I detect the nearest letter near the click location and insert the caret there, but I believe it's tedious.*

I found [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/3296786/). is there any follow up regarding to a solution? Thanks.

**Update**

The `span` element is interfering with the range.

```js
$("#c").click(function(e) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
 
  $("#res").get(0).textContent = "START_OFFSET:" + range.startOffset + "-> " + range.startContainer.innerHTML;
 console.log(range.startContainer);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="c" contenteditable="true">
    TEST
  </div>
  <span id="res"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether there are other ranges? `window.getSelection ().rangeCount` should tell you.

Comment: @NikxDa Yes, the count is 1. I've added it to the snippet.

Comment: I can not find any reason that this might not be working, except for the span somehow interfering with the index. Is there any reason that you cannot use `selectionStart`, or have you tried it? I cannot use Edge on OSX, so my testing is limited in the moment.

Comment: @NikxDa The span element is interfering with the range value. I've tried the removing the span just the **<div>TEST</div>** the range is correct. This is the first time I came about **selectionStart** but I think it's for text areas and not content editable - correct me if I'm wrong but I'll try.

Comment: I've also updated your pen so you can test easily: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzZBEQ

Comment: Plus, I've filed a bug report: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14297319/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've narrowed down the problem and the `<span>` is the root of all evil.

The `span`s text is wrapped inside a text element, in which you are navigating (`[Object Text]`, check the `startContainer` property). After the last char, the text element ends, the `span` however does not. So you're now after the text element (index 0) and at the first index in the `span`. Other major browsers do not have this problem, because the text element continues after the last character. This is most likely an Edge bug.

Remove the `span` to solve the problem.