# Determining Caret Position Beforehand

Tags: javascript, html

For example:

Using `|` as an caret identifier

```
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Sta|ckOverflow</span>
```

If I push the up arrow key, caret position will be

```
<span>Hel|lo</span>
<span>StackOverflow</span>
```

For this example sake, these spans are inside a contentEditable div.

How can I compute the [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) manually so that I can position the caret between the the two L's.

From a base range of:

```
startOffset/endOffset: 3, startContainer/endContainer: Hello(text node)
```

how can I compute the future caret position if an arrow key was pressed. If up arrow key was pressed, the result would be:

```
startOffset/endOffset: 3, startContainer/endContainer: Hello(text node)
```

Its like:

```
function getFutureRange(keyboardMouseEvent,oldRange){
/*some code here*/
return futureRange; //spits out startOffset/endOffset: 3, startContainer/endContainer: Hello(text node)
}
```

I don't necessarily need a code. Just APIs, documentation, or concept to get started with.

I just want to know how range is computed by the selection ranging from contentEditable, textAreas, text inputs, etc...why? in relation to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815472/range-and-caret-position-doesnt-match), the selection varies browser to browser.

*I can't think of any solution right now except using `getClientRects()` and compute the offsets(width, height) by getting each character's rects. I don't know how to get the character's rects. Pretty much I'm stuck and I don't know if that is the optimal way to do that.*

Comment: Would you mind to explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RomanCortes I want to know the underlying computation of selection or range so that it can position the caret properly. I can't find docs/API about it though.

Comment: But, are you trying to create a text editor, maybe? If so, why you are not using contentEditable? Would you mind to explain the context a bit better?

Comment: @RomanCortes yep, I'm editing the question right now.

Comment: I see, so you want to figure out the range before it is set. I don't believe there is anything available for that, so you will probably will need to use getClientRects. However, will that match all OSs/browsers? You will need to test a lot

Comment: Good luck. I worked years ago in something related, and the browser differences between contentEditable and the ranges were crazy. I'm not sure if you read an article from Google about Google Docs, they ended not using contentEditable but reimplementing all...

Comment: @RomanCortes Thanks! Standardizing these ranges are tedious and I just found out unicode caret positioning are also different  FF, GC. Yep, I read a little about their layout/rendering(?) engine.